# Connection pentaho to Neo4j database : Error

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, pentaho

I downloaded the community version of pentaho to create dashboards. 
I have a Neo4j database on my PC with my datas.
When I try to connect my report to my Neo4j database, I have an error that I can't resolve.

I added the Neo4j connector tht I found on the marketplace in my report-design/lib/jdbc file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRVSN.jpg

I open pentaho, I create a new report and I add a new JDBC connection of type generic database with the following informations :

Connection type as Generic database
Custom connection URL as jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474
Custom driver class name as org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver

https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lU3.jpg

Neo4j is On

And when I click on test I have the following error :

```
Erreur lors de la connexion à la Base de données [Neo4j connection] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver)
Internal Connector Error


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver)
Internal Connector Error


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:71)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:250)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:254)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$AddDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:252)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.setVisible(CommonDialog.java:230)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:158)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:798)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:71)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:70)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver)
Internal Connector Error

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:587)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1202)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1069)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1044)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:950)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:658)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:131)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.getDiscoveryResource(Neo4jConnection.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Connections.create(Connections.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:36)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:336)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:114)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:112)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:180)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1136)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1610)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1171)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1610)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1171)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1225)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1068)
    ... 142 more

URL personnalisée       :jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474
Classe pilote personnalisé       :org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
```

I can not find the solution if someone can help me, it would be wonderful. Thank you !!!

Comment: try following this tutorial http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/#_pentaho

Answer (score -1):

Try copy Driver Neo4j this path: %pantaho_home%\lib

I'm using  neo4j-jdbc-driver-4.0.2.jar driver.

Hope I helped with your problem

Comment: The OP left the driver in the correct path for Pentaho Report Designer, each Pentaho tool has a slightly different path for jdbc drivers, your path is valid for Pentaho Data Integration, but not for Pentaho Report Designer